# ThreadLocal doesn`t hold the value until next api call

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, rest, thread-safety

I am trying to call an API that sets a value of a `ThreadLocal`, and then with all the others API to get that specific value that was previously set. The problem is that the local thread doesn`t keep the value so by any other api call, i get the null value. What should I do ?

**SignUpController.java:**

```
    @GetMapping("validate/mobileNo")
    public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> validateMobileNoForSignUp(@RequestParam("countryCode") String countryCode,
                                                                 @RequestParam("mobileNo") String mobileNo,
                                                                 @RequestParam("accountType") String accountType) {
        
        System.out.println("Value from /validate/mobileNo = " + LocationContextHolder.holder.get());
        LocationContextHolder.holder.set("random_value_to_be_set_and_read");
        System.out.println("Value from /validate/mobileNo SERVICE = " + LocationContextHolder.holder.get());
        
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new ApiResponse<>(null, null));
    }

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PostMapping("/profile")
    public Long postProfile(@Valid @RequestBody SignUpDto signUpDTO) {
        
        System.out.println("Value from /profile = " + LocationContextHolder.holder.get());
        
        return null;
    }
```

**LocationContextHolder.java:**

```
public class LocationContextHolder {
    public static final ThreadLocal<String> holder = new ThreadLocal<>();
}
```

And then I start the thread from main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewThread t1 = new NewThread();
        t1.start();
    }
```

**NewThread.java:**

```
public class NewThread extends Thread{

    public void callGetEndpoint() throws IOException {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        //Http call implementation
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    }

    public void callPostEndpint() throws IOException {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        //Http call implementation
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    }



    public void run() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int i = 0;
        while (i<1) {
            System.out.println(this.getName() + ": Thread is running..." + i++);
            try {
                //Wait for one sec so it doesn't print too fast
                callGetEndpoint();
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                callPostEndpint();
//                Thread.sleep(10000);
                i++;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the **result:**

```
Value from /validate/mobileNo = null
Value from /validate/mobileNo SERVICE = random_value_to_be_set_and_read
Value from /profile = null
```

Comment: Why you use ThreadLocal, why not using static variable? If you need it to be shared across the threads.

Comment: The thing is named `ThreadLocal` for a reason. The value is bound to a thread, a request is handled by a thread. Each request is handled with a different thread, ergo setting something with request 1 into a `ThreadLocal` doesn't make it visisble to request 2 which comes afterwards as that is executed ina  different thread.

Comment: Deinum, are they executed in a different thread even if I create a single thread that perform both calls ? I have to admit I am not very familiar to this subject. So please give me a solution that I can store the value.